# "Cannot set property 'background' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript

So, I'm making a small game in which you're suposed to click in as much red circles you can in a certain amount of time(the time is still not defined). But the idea that I have in mind is, having circles in the screen, all black/white in exception to one, that is red. And you're suposed to click in the red circle. When you click on it, another one turns red, and so far, until times up. The problem is I can even set the background of only one of the circles to red(it's suposed to be aleatorious). So, any help is apreciated. Thanks in advance!

This is the HTML file:

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <button class="square number-0"></button>
      <button class="square number-1"></button>
      <button class="square number-2"></button>
      <button class="square number-3"></button>
(...)
      <button class="square number-47"></button>
      <button type="button" class="retry">Retry Play</button>
    </div>

  </body>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

And this is the javascript file:

```
const squares = document.querySelector('.square');
const retry = document.querySelector('.retry');


retry.addEventListener('click', function(){
  let circle = Math.floor(Math.random()*squares.length);
  let number = `number-${circle}`;
  number.style.background = 'red';
});
```

Comment: `number-${circle}` is a string, I'd say `String` has no `.style` property.

Comment: Since your number variable is not a DOM element so you cant use the element's display type (`.style`) into it.

Comment: By the way, it says squares because at the beguining they were suposed to be squares but then I changed it to circles

Comment: so what sould I use instead of .style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues in your code:

- squares need to be querySelectorAll to return a node element array
- number need to be a querySelector to get the node, then apply the style background that you want

```js
const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
const retry = document.querySelector('.retry');


retry.addEventListener('click', function(){
  let circle = Math.floor(Math.random()*squares.length);
  let number = `.number-${circle}`;
  document.querySelector(number).style.background = 'red';
});
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <button class="square number-0"></button>
      <button class="square number-1"></button>
      <button class="square number-2"></button>
      <button class="square number-3"></button>
(...)
      <button class="square number-47"></button>
      <button type="button" class="retry">Retry Play</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: thank you! it worked. Just one more thing, I've tried to give the same function to the "squares buttons" so that after having appered the first circle you can than click on the circle and make other circles turn red to. But for this circles it says "squares.addEventListener is not a function". This is how I coded:
    squares.addEventListener('click', function(){
  let circle = Math.floor(Math.random()*squares.length);
  let number = `.number-${circle}`;
  document.querySelector(number).style.background = 'red';
});

Comment: @AntónioAbranchesPinto i need to check the code could you post on codepen or similar?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose

```
document.querySelector(`.number-${circle}`).style.background = 'red';
```

should do the trick. So

```
retry.addEventListener('click', function(){
  let circle = Math.floor(Math.random()*squares.length);
  document.querySelector(`.number-${circle}`)
    .style.background = 'red';
});
```